# Ubuntu will not load with kernel 5.11.0-25-generic

Tags: 20.04, kernel, updates, visual-artifacts

Ubuntu updated to kernel 5.11.0-25-generic and will no longer load.  It goes through the non graphic stuff and eventually goes to a flashing `_` . That `_` eventually disappears and vertical green lines flash on my screen.

If I tell GRUB to load kernel 5.8.0-63-generic-boot, Ubuntu 20.04.2 loads correctly. I am fairly new with Linux so please be patient with me.

Comment: You've provided no details of your system, nor if talking about desktop or server?  You can always opt to use the GA stack (ie. stick to *stable*  GA 5.4 kernel; LTS releases have two kernel stack choices selected at install time, unless changed) but more details may allow us to give more.  Did you boot to recovery or runlevel 1 (at grub you can use the 'e' key to edit the boot entry; putting a ' 1' on the linux kernel line will cause boot to stop at runlevel 1) & check out the 5.11 kernel boots? or any other exploration using 5.11?  Can you login to a text terminal? (ctrl+alt+F4 for example)

Comment: As I said I am nowhere near fluent in Linux hence why I have turned for help. I tried Linux because of all the people who claim that the Linux community is friendly and always ready to help. If I knew what I was doing I would not be asking for help.  GA stack, runlevel are alien to me. I am running a desktop. I do not have the knowledge to run a server. I went through an upgrade and now all I have is a blank screen when Linux load the kernel I mentioned in my question.  I only managed to get back on Linux after I reloaded Ubuntu 20.04 beside my existing linux and grub gave me two options.

Comment: Yes ctrl+alt+F4 did work after the 4th try.  What do I do with that?

Comment: @JosephAndre Most people here are more than willing to help you. When they ask you for more information, they don't do that to judge you or your Linux fluency. They do that because they want to understand what's going on with your system in order to help you solve this. Without the info they ask about, it might be impossible for you to get a solution. Also, please don't be intimidated by some terminology you might not be familiar with. If you need more explanation about something, that's what comments and chat (thought you need a bit more rep to access that) are for.

Comment: Just another note: When commenting, you can ping someone to let them know that you commented, by using a `@` in front of their username. Otherwise people won't know that you added a comment. Here, @guiverc has probably not seen your comments. This time they will get notified by me, since I pinged them using `@guiverc` in my previous sentence.

Comment: I didn't see your reply until BeastOfCaerbannog *(I removed the @ on purpose as I don't see need for him to read this*) pinged me. Ctrl.Alt.F4 lets you use a text terminal to make changes that may fix things. In your case I'd install the GA kernel until I had time to *resolve* the issue (in time you'll likely find it'll resolve itself; as when bugs are filed, the *devs* will finally see the issue (more bugs, more *heat* & time gets allocated to fix it) and resolutions will get there. If you have time for filing bugs, great! but for now I'd work around the issue first using GA kernel.

Comment: Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  and look for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel*" which provides a command to install it on your 20.04 box. The text login allows you to enter commands, ie. use your normal username & password to login, and you'll find yourself at a `bash` or $ prompt.  On reboot you'll have 5.4 kernels that I'm betting will work the entire life of 20.04.  If you've new hardware you may have other issues that make it *less than ideal* solution; but it's what I'd try.  I don't know if you're using Nvidia drivers so I don't know if you need that too

Comment: After nvidia it goes to "*If everything is good, you may remove the other kernel flavours:*" but I would **not** do that.  I'd leave HWE installed as it may get fixed in time, then you can return to using it.  After install, you can logout/reboot & at the grub menu select a 5.4 kernel option & see how that look (everything works etc, no *regressions* for you etc).  GA = general stable kernel, HWE is hardware enablement, which allows for additional hardware *drivers* (technically kernel modules) but isn't as *stable*.  Server installs opt for GA by default for stability.

Comment: You could search launchpad for bugs, even file one using `ubuntu-bug linux` (but that requires `firefox` to allow you to sign in, or else type the long URL onto another working box where you can complete the bug report). The bug tracker (launchpad) will look for like bugs, and it will quite probably find on, meaning you can just use the "*affects me too*" issue where you can leave a comment with details of your hardware, upload a picture showing the issue etc.  Filing your own bug provides the max detail though https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I have the same problem with ubuntu 20.04 linux kernel 5.11.0.25 and linux kernel 5.11.0.27 with Nvidia driver 340.108 installed. When i use the linux kernel 5.8, it works fine...